# How can I pass a struct compound literal to a function as argument?

Tags: c, compound-literals

Here is a `struct` that I have:

```
typedef struct 
{
    float r, g, b;
} color_t;
```

I'd like to pass a compound literal of this `struct` to a function as argument, like this:

```
void printcolor(color_t c)
{
    printf("color is : %f %f %f\n", c.r, c.g, c.b);
}

printcolor({1.0f, 0.6f, 0.8f});
```

However, this gives me an error:

> error: expected expression before '{' token

Comment: `printcolor((color_t) {1.0f, 0.6f, 0.8f});` Don't be fooled by the cast-like syntax. It's not a cast, it's still a compound literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) in C *must* have the type specified (using 'cast-like' syntax) before the brace-enclosed initializer list. So, as mentioned in the comments, you should change your function call to:

```c
printcolor((color_t){1.0f, 0.6f, 0.8f});
```